Mock function in MockKnex is not creating a new object
I am running some unit tests after a node version upgrade and jest version upgrade in package.json.
The unit test attempts to mock a knex config.
import { mock as mockKnex, getTracker } from "mock-knex";
import { postgresConnectionPool } from "../../src/database/PostgresConnectionPool";

mockKnex(postgresConnectionPool); // This line is erroring out

describe("Test Suites", () => {
  // test cases
})

However this is erroring out because a new object of mockKnex is not created. The error is TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '_setAdapter')
// This code is from mock-knex public library
value: function mock(db) {
  this._setAdapter(db); // It is failing on this line because the this object is undefined

  return this._adapter.mock(db);
}

One of my questions is why is this happening ? Is it a jest issue or node issue ?
